# thread and making a Timer with QLCDNumber

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

The following code just makes a `QTimer` with `QLCDNumber`. I want to show a message dialog when 4s have elapsed since the startup of the program. However, when the message dialog pops up, the time on `QLCDNumber` doesn’t change. What should I do to make this program keep timing even when the message dialog pops up?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800,600)

        self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcdNumber.setNumDigits(8)

        layout =  QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)

        self.currentTime = QTime(0,0,0)
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss'))

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLcdNumberContent)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def updateLcdNumberContent(self):

        self.currentTime = self.currentTime.addSecs(1)
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.currentTime.toString('hh:mm:ss'))


        if self.currentTime == QTime(0,0,4) :
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setWindowTitle('iTimer')
            msgBox.setIcon (QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setText("Time Out !!")

            stopButton = msgBox.addButton("Stop", QMessageBox.ActionRole)
            ignoreButton = msgBox.addButton(QMessageBox.Ignore)

            stopButton.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)


            msgBox.show()
#            msgBox.exec_()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app =QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
msgBox = QMessageBox(self)
```

to create a non-blocking message box. You can remove the exec_() method.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,but now I have another 2 questions both within my code .
1)if QmessageBox’s parent is None , show() shows QmessageBox only for a second ,then it disappeared immediately .why this issue occurs ?
2)why does giving the QMessageBox my QMainWindow as a parent create a non-blocking message box ?

Comment: 1.) I think setting the parent to None triggers the Garbage Collection.

2.) It says so in the docs.

Please accept the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: please give me the link that you mentioned in your answers.I just checked the doc ,only found "The parent argument, if not None, causes self to be owned by Qt instead of PyQt." is this what you mean ? neither do I understand this